# How to connect to Odoo database from an android application

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I am developping an Android application, and I'd like to retrieve data from an Odoo server.

For that I developped a custom module in Odoo, in which I created a controller.

## My controller :

```
import json
import xmlrpc.client as xmlrpclib
from odoo import http
from openerp.http import Response

class resUserController(http.Controller):
    url = '<my url>'
    db = '<name of my database>'

    @http.route('/user/login', type='json', method='GET', auth='public')
    def get_login(self, **kwargs):
        username = kwargs.get('email')
        password = kwargs.get('password')
        common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(self.url), allow_none=True)

        uid = common.authenticate(self.db, username, password, {})
        if uid:
            Response.status = '200 Succesful operation'
            json_result = {'token': uid}
            return json.dumps(json_result)
        Response.status = '400 Invalid credentials'
        return
```

When I call it from a python script to try it, it works fine and I get a `<Response [200]>` and a json `{u'jsonrpc': u'2.0', u'result': u'{"token": 8}', u'id': None}` with the id of the account I connect to.

But then I have an other function I call with an other route in the same controller, but with `auth='user'` this time, because I want the user to be able to see only informations he has rights on.

```
@http.route('/user/getInfo', type='json', method='GET', auth='user')
def get_info(self, **kwargs):
    uid = 1
    password = '<my admin password>'
    models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(self.url), allow_none=True)
    info = models.execute_kw(self.db, uid, password, 'res.users',
                             'search_read', [[['id', '=', kwargs.get('token')]]],
                             {'fields': ['info']})[0]['invite_code']
    if info:
        Response.status = '200 Succesful operation'
        json_result = {'info': info}
        return json.dumps(json_result)
    Response.status = '404 User not found'
    return
```

This function works fine when I use `auth='public'`, but when I go for `auth='user'`, I get the following json response :

> Response [200]
>
> ```
> {  
>     u'jsonrpc': u'2.0',   
>     u'id': None,   
>     u'error': {  
>         u'message': u'Odoo Session Expired',   
>         u'code': 100,  
>         u'data': {  
>             u'debug': u'Traceback (most recent call last):  
>                       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 650, in _handle_exception  
>                       return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)  
>                       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception  
>                       raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])  
>                       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise  
>                       raise value  
>                       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/http_routing/models/ir_http.py", line 342, in _dispatch  
>                       cls._authenticate(func.routing[\'auth\'])  
>                       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 117, in _authenticate  
>                       getattr(cls, "_auth_method_%s" % auth_method)()  
>                       File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 90, in _auth_method_user  
>                       raise http.SessionExpiredException("Session expired")  
>                       odoo.http.SessionExpiredException: Session expired',   
>             u'exception_type': u'internal_error',   
>             u'message': u'Session expired',   
>             u'name': u'odoo.http.SessionExpiredException',  
>             u'arguments': [u'Session expired'] 
>         }  
>     }  
> }
> ```

I based my work on [This documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/webservices/odoo.html), which is an official Odoo doc, but here are the problems :

**1** It ask me to write my admin password in each function, which seems dangerous.

**2** After authentication, I get the id of my user, but no **session token**. Then how can I inform my function with `auth='user'` that I'm connected and to which user?

Here is my script to test my calls :

```
import requests
import json

url_connect = "<my url>/user/login"
url = "<my url>/user/getInfo"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
data_connect = {
                "params": {
                           "email": "<my test account email>",
                           "password": "<my test account password>",
                }
    }
data = {
        "params": {
                   "token": <my test account id>,
            }
       }
data_json = json.dumps(data)
r = requests.get(url=url_connect, data=json.dumps(data_connect), headers=headers)
print(r)
print(r.json())
r = requests.get(url=url, data=data_json, headers=headers)
print(r)
print(r.json())
```

Comment: I aslo tried to connect using "<my url>/web/session/authenticate" which is a built in controller of odoo. It works fine, and returns me a session ID. But how can I use this sessionID then? I'd try to pass it into my params, but doesn't works better, I still have the same answer of "Odoo session expired"

Comment: " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191576/sid-session-id-changed-when-call-new-api "

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Things to note:

- Never send credentials in a GET request
- All Odoo RPC requests are **POST** requests
- You don't need a custom login route if you use **/web/session/authenticate**
- The **External API** is intended to be used outside of odoo framework. When developing a module use self.env['< model >'] if inside a model or http.request.env['< model >'] if in a controller
- The call to **/web/session/authenticate** returns a json containing the session_id, which you have to pass it in the **cookies** to subsequent requests until you call **/web/session/destroy** to logout.

Here is an example using **/web/session/autenticate**:

```
import requests
import json

url_connect = "http://localhost:8069/web/session/authenticate"
url = "http://localhost:8069/web/session/get_session_info"

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

data_connect = {
    "params": {
        "db": "demo1",
        "login": "admin",
        "password": "admin",
    }
}

data = {}

session = requests.Session()

r = session.post(url=url_connect, data=json.dumps(data_connect), headers=headers)

if r.ok:
    result = r.json()['result']

    if result.get('session_id'):
        session.cookies['session_id'] = result.get('session_id')

r = session.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
print(r)
print(r.json())
```

To get the info from your controller you could use request.env.user which holds the logged user at the moment and since you specify auth='user' it is required to be a valid. The sample code might look like:

```
from odoo.http import request

class UserController(http.Controller):
  @http.route('/user/getInfo', type='json', method='POST', auth='user')
  def get_info(self, **kwargs):
    current_user = request.env.user

    Response.status = '200 Succesful operation'
    json_result = {'info': current_user.info}
    return json.dumps(json_result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Very well write question, you have done the homework. This works for me to be able to authenticate the mobile users sessions using an api style requests.

```
@http.route([
    '/m/login/email',
], type='http', auth="public", website=True, methods=["POST"], csrf=False)
def users_login_email(self, **kwargs):
    if kwargs:
        data = json.loads(kwargs.keys()[0])
    else:
        data = json.loads(request.httprequest.data)

    email = data.get('email')
    password = data.get('password')

    if not request.session.db:
        setup_db()
    uid = request.session.authenticate(request.session.db, email, password)
    if uid:
        return self._user_details(uid)
    body = json.dumps({"body": ["Credenciales Incorrectas"]})
    return werkzeug.wrappers.Response(body, status=403, headers=[
        ('Content-Type', 'application/json'), ('Content-Length', len(body))
    ])
```

Also I didn't use `auth='user'` to don't let Odoo to mess with redirects and web stuffs checks. I use this annotation wrapper in my controllers routes that require an authenticated user to return the proper HTTP error status code

```
def check_user(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if not request.session.db:
            setup_db()

        request.uid = request.session.uid

        if not request.uid:
            body = json.dumps({"body": ["Session Expired"]})
            return werkzeug.wrappers.Response(body, status=403, headers=[
                ('Content-Type', 'application/json'), ('Content-Length', len(body))
            ])

        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrap
```

You could use it like this:

```
@check_user
@http.route([
    '/m/<int:shop_id>/cart/info',
], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def cart_info(self, shop_id, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution without basic Odoo's http redirections. It might become a problem and if so, I'll try your solution.